# Failed to continue: Check the debug console for details

Tags: visual-studio-code

OS: MacOS OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

GO: go1.11.2 darwin/amd64

VSCODE: 1.29.1 (bc24f98b5f70467bc689abf41cc5550ca637088e)

dlv: 1.1.0 (1990ba12450cab9425a2ae62e6ab988725023d5c)

GO EXTENSIONS: ms-vscode.go 0.7.0

**When I perform "Start debugging" operation, the vscode popup a dialog as below:
[error message from vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvaJE.jpg)
I click the button "Open launch.json", it open the file launch.json, but no message in "DEBUG CONSOLE" panel.**

Should you tell me why and how to fix this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, installing the Xcode Command Line Tools solved it for me: xcode-select --install